# Order the legend names in ggplot2 object from smaller to larger

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have the dataframe below and I want to set the order of the legend names from smaller to larger. The values may be characters but they have correspondence to the `Cases` column which I believe could be useful since the dataset is dynamic.

[image]

```
Cum<-structure(list(Age.group = c("00-04", "00-04", "05-14", "05-14", 
                                  "15-24", "15-24", "25-49", "25-49", "50-64", "50-64", "65-79", 
                                  "65-79", "80+", "80+"), Gender = c("Female", "Male", "Female", 
                                                                     "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
                                                                     "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"), Cases = c(64578, 70518, 
                                                                                                                    187568, 197015, 414405, 388138, 1342394, 1206168, 792180, 742744, 
                                                                                                                    400232, 414613, 282268, 198026), lab = c("64,578", "70,518", 
                                                                                                                                                             "187,568", "197,015", "414,405", "388,138", "1,342,394", "1,206,168", 
                                                                                                                                                             "792,180", "742,744", "400,232", "414,613", "282,268", "198,026"
                                                                                                                    ), Age.group.Sum = c(135096, 135096, 384583, 384583, 802543, 
                                                                                                                                         802543, 2548562, 2548562, 1534924, 1534924, 814845, 814845, 480294, 
                                                                                                                                         480294), lab2 = c("135,096", "135,096", "384,583", "384,583", 
                                                                                                                                                           "802,543", "802,543", "2,548,562", "2,548,562", "1,534,924", 
                                                                                                                                                           "1,534,924", "814,845", "814,845", "480,294", "480,294"), color = c("#4285f4", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "#4285f4", "#90a9e0", "#90a9e0", "#dd9e5f", "#dd9e5f", "#b45f06", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "#b45f06", "#b45f06", "#b45f06", "#dd9e5f", "#dd9e5f", "#aebbd6", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "#90a9e0"), Range = c("LESS THAN 74.5K", "LESS THAN 74.5K", "148.9K - 223.4K", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "148.9K - 223.4K", "372.3K - 446.7K", "372.3K - 446.7K", "MORE THAN 670.1K", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "MORE THAN 670.1K", "MORE THAN 670.1K", "MORE THAN 670.1K", "372.3K - 446.7K", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "372.3K - 446.7K", "223.4K - 297.8K", "148.9K - 223.4K")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    -14L))

names(mycols) <- mycols
ylab <- c(0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5)
lbls <- setNames(unique(Cum$color), unique(Cum$Range))
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
ggplot_obj <- ggplot(data = Cum, aes(x = `Age.group`, y = Cases, group = Gender,fill = Range)) +
  geom_bar(aes(
   
    text = paste("<b>Gender:</b>", Gender, "<br><b>Age:</b>", `Age.group` ,
                 "<br><b>Cases:</b>", lab, "<br><b>Total cases in age group:</b>",
                 lab2)), 
    position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = Cases + 10000, label = Gender), vjust = 1,
            position = position_dodge(width=0.9),size=2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = lbls) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(Cum$Cases)*1.1), expand = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()+ theme(
    # remove the vertical grid lines
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line()
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))+
  xlab("Age group")
```

Comment: Can you show the order you wanted

Comment: LESS THAN 74.5K should be 1st and then based on the numeric value they have from smaller to larger

Comment: but the values may all be dynamic and even there may be more legend names than 5

Comment: can you check the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could convert the column to `factor` with `levels` specified in the custom order

```
Cum$Range <- factor(Cum$Range, levels = c("LESS THAN 74.5K" , "148.9K - 223.4K" , "223.4K - 297.8K", "372.3K - 446.7K" ,  "MORE THAN 670.1K"))
ylab <- c(0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5)
lbls <- setNames(Cum$color[match(levels(Cum$Range), Cum$Range)], levels(Cum$Range))
```

Construct the plot with `ggplot` as in the OP's code

-output

[image]

#### Update

If the 'Range' values are dynamic (assuming the unit is the same), then extract the numeric part with `parse_number`, `order` and get the `unique` values

```
lvls <- as.character(unique(Cum$Range[order(readr::parse_number(as.character(Cum$Range)))]))
Cum$Range <- factor(Cum$Range, levels = lvls)
```

Or another option is to `arrange` by 'Cases` and set the levels for 'Range'

```
library(dplyr)
Cum <-  Cum %>% 
         arrange(Cases, Age.group) %>%
         mutate(Range = factor(Range, levels = unique(Range)))
lbls <- setNames(Cum$color[match(levels(Cum$Range), Cum$Range)], levels(Cum$Range))
```

Comment: the Range names may be dynamic and different than 5

Comment: @firmo23 that is fine.  Only thing is that the `levels` have to be specified manually because it is a custom order as there are characters and numbers involved

Comment: they may have diifferent names every time. can the Cases column could be used in order to set the order?

Comment: @firmo23 What is meant is that your values 'LESS THAN 74.5K' is not numeric.  It could be converted to numeric with `unique(Cum$Range[order(readr::parse_number(Cum$Range))])`

Comment: it works but its Cum$Range not CumRange thanks

Comment: @firmo23 I added two more options.  I think any of them should work