# R ggplot colour coding lines by data frame column

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm working on a plot that has up to 51 lines plotted and I would like the last line plotted in the group to be plotted in a different colour, line thickness and line type using ggplot. The reason here is that the last line plotted is the input model for some simulations and all the other lines are simulation outcomes. I have this process working using Base R code but it is very convoluted with many loops and I'm expecting ggplot to be more straightforward.

Below I've tried to simplify the problem to just three lines using the iris dataset.

```
# Code the species with some colours
tmp <- iris %>% 
       mutate(Spc = as.numeric(Species)) %>% 
       mutate(Clr = if_else(Spc == 1 , "red", "grey"))

# create the plot
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Species, colour = Clr))
```

A few questions here.  Firstly out of interest I could not get 'if_else' to work with a factor variable. I convert the factor for Species to a number to get a result and I suspect that this was a fluke rather than understanding. I would like an example of how to use a factor or character variable in this type of conditional statement using dplyr. I also had a play with 'case_when' hoping to be able to set a different colour for each of three species but could not get that to work.

Secondly, while the plot produced does seem to have one colour for 'setosa' and the same colour for the other two species the colours are not the ones I specified? I also need to sort out the legend so it says something like "Setosa" and "Others" for the two colour options
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of understanding the issue, would be this what you want to do?

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = Species, colour = (Species == "setosa"))) +
    scale_color_discrete(labels = c("Other", "Setosa"), name = "Species")
```

[image]

Or

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = Species, colour = (Species == "setosa"))) +
    scale_color_manual(labels = c("Other", "Setosa"), name = "Species", values = c("brown", "yellow"))
```

[image]

Comment: Clearly, my question was poorly phrased.  I'm aware of this solution - was looking for a solution where I could include the colour in the input data and then set the colour from there.

Comment: May you help this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67780876/ggplot-object-does-not-color-bars-according-to-color-specified-in-the-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

In the `aes()`-call you're telling ggplot which variable to map to which output characteristic, so it "reads" your `colour = clr` as input variable - therefore, the legend says "grey" and "red". You can use `scale_colour_manual` to map input values to colour-values that ggplot draws:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width,
               group = Species, colour = Species)) + 
    geom_line() +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "grey", "grey"))
```

Comment: My question was poorly phrased it seems.  I was looking for a solution whereby I could read the colours from the underlying table and also control the legend from the unique values in that table.